# Windows Defender identifying my program as multiple trojans("Wacatac" & "Persistence") - presumably caused by overwriting a Registry Key

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

The 2 trojans:

[Wacatac.G!ml](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/malware-encyclopedia-description?name=Trojan%3AWin32%2FWacatac.G!ml&threatid=2147749376)

[image: wacatac]

[Persistence.G!ml](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/wdsi/threats/threat-search?query=Behavior:Win32/Persistence.GI!ml)

[image: persistence]

Here's the code that I believe is causing the issue. The purpose is to create/modify a registry key to make the program run on startup:

```
void SoftwareDlg::SetSURegValue() {
    string regSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run\\");
    string regValueName = "Software";
    string regValue = "D:\\Users\\Skew\\Documents\\repos\\Software\\Debug\\Software.exe"

    try
    {
        size_t bufferSize = 0xFFF;
        auto cbData = static_cast<DWORD>(regValue.size() * sizeof(char));
        HKEY hKey;
        DWORD position;
        
        auto rc = RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, regSubKey.c_str(), 0, NULL, REG_OPTION_NON_VOLATILE, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hKey, &position);
        if (position == REG_OPENED_EXISTING_KEY) {
            DEBUG_PRINT("Key already exists & has been opened.")
        }
        else if (position == REG_CREATED_NEW_KEY) {
            DEBUG_PRINT("Created new key.")
        }
        else {
            DEBUG_PRINT("ERROR: Key does not exist, and a new key was not created.")
        }

        if (rc == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
            auto rc = RegSetValueEx(hKey, regValueName.c_str(), 0, REG_SZ, (BYTE*)regValue.data(), cbData);
            if (rc != ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Windows system error code: " + to_string(rc));
            }
        }
        else {
            DEBUG_PRINT("Error opening key.\n")
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        DEBUG_PRINT(e.what())
    }
}
```

In my attempts to solve this issue I began testing different scenarios of creating/modifying the key, but my results became inconclusive when I realized that Windows Defender had seemingly stopped logging each run as "new threats" and seemed to log them together as a single "permeant threat" I guess? Not really sure.

With that said, Windows Defender did not seem to log the threat when I would initially create the key or when I would open it and assign it the same value, but did appear to log the threat when I would move the program to a new directory(and the program would attempt to change the value of the "Software" registry value to the new EXE location).

That's left me with several questions:

1. Does my program mimic the behavior of the 2 trojans through some coding mistake?
2. Or do I have some latent, opportunistic piece of malware on my machine that's just been waiting to take advantage?
3. Is deleting the existing value necessary before attempting to change it? The behavior of `RegCreateKeyEx` leads me to believe this is not the case.
4. Is writing to the registry without elevated permissions a no-no? If so... why does my machine let me do it?
5. Am I doing some incorrect type conversion in the `RegSetValueEx()` function?

If #4 is the case, I guess I'm just really surprised that I was notified by Windows Defender and not Visual Studio or a UAC prompt.

Edit 1: [No engines on VirusTotal.com detected the file as malware.](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/file/523dab5bbdcd0460756174775da6ca075d67952d642cc49d20829e7546a9d85f/detection)

Comment: I added that function to my project and Windows Defender scanned it as no threat. Are you sure that's it? Did you comment out the contents of the function and have the problem go away?

Comment: Yes, when I remove the function the problem appears to go away. Can you try running that same program from a different location?

Comment: *3* and *4* of course no. for what you use *string* here ? why *A* instead *W* ? and why you not ask - why *Windows Defender* mistake, instead search mistake in your code

Comment: @RbMm "A" instead of "W" just allows me to use regular strings & cstrings that the rest of my program uses. "why you not ask - why Windows Defender mistake". I've written enough bad code to know that everything is the devs fault lol

Comment: in concrete case exclusively guilty Windows Defender. i be of course use *W*, not use string at all here (for what), but plain L"..." strings. but all this unrelated to windows defender false detect

Comment: The only mistakes I see are 1) not including the null terminator in `cbData`, as required by `REG_SZ` (use [`RegSetKeyValue()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-regsetkeyvaluea) to avoid that), and 2) evaluating `position` before checking `rc` to make sure `position` is valid. Aside from that, the act of accessing a Registry key, especially one under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER`, should not be enough to trigger Windows Defender, so something else is likely going on. What does `DEBUG_PRINT()` look like exactly? That is the only other factor to consider.

Comment: @RemyLebeau, I thought resolving #1 fixed my issue, but sadly it did not. DEBUG_PRINT is just a simple macro to allow me to shove strings into OutputDebugString() and automatically follow them up with a new line:
```

 inline void OutputDebug(string OutputString){
  OutputDebugString(OutputString.c_str());
  OutputDebugString("\n");
 }
#if _DEBUG
#define DEBUG_PRINT(x)  OutputDebug(x);
#else
#define DEBUG_PRINT(x)   
#endif

```

Comment: @Skewjo each string passed to `OutputDebugString()` is handled by debuggers as a separate string for display, so there is no need to output a line break by itself. But, if you really need to, it would make more sense to use `OutputDebugString((OutputString+"\n").c_str())` instead. In any case, your issue is most likely related to a false positive in WD itself, like RbRm said, not a real fault in your code.